# Python Dataflow job has an extremely slow startup time

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow

As a test of a much bigger python dataflow pipeline I'm working with a subset of my data of size: 283.55 MB. The top parent of my dataflow graph is a simple beam.io.ReadFromText that takes around 30 seconds to read this file. This 30 seconds is taken from the Wall time field in the Summary Step. However, this step takes up to 10+ minutes to start. Can anyone answer why I have such a massive startup time for such a small amount of data? It should be noted that I have a setup file (--setup_file .\setup.py), requirements file (--requirements_file requirements.txt), and --save_main_session True). The contents of my requirements file are:

numpy==1.13.3
pandas==0.20.3
scikit-learn==0.19.1
scipy==0.19.1

Why does my job take so long to start? Do my requirements really take that long to install on the cluster? Here is viz of the job sitting and doing nothing for a while:

[image]

Comment: What runner are you using?

For Dataflow, it has to start up the workers and get everything started. This can sometimes take a bit of time. 10 minutes is a bit long though. 
If on Dataflow, and you provide a job id, I can take a look at the specific job.

Comment: I'll gladly provide a jobId, but not through StackOverflow. Do you have a feedback email for dataflow? My team has previously used cloudml-feedback@google.com.

Comment: @LaraSchmidt I'd love to send you these job IDs

Comment: @Andrew, you can open a support ticket in your project Support Center to convey job IDs to Google engineers. Make sure to refer to this SO post in your support ticket.

Comment: I ended up upgrading google-cloud-dataflow to 2.3.0 from 2.1.1 and removing all my requirements.txt. I realized all the requirements were already installed on all the workers per: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies. This seemed to speed things up.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was trying to find a proper, externally available email and then had forgotten to check back up. A support ticket would be the best though.

Glad you got it working.

Comment: @AndrewCassidy we've seen about 4-5 minutes on ours and I would love to speed them up.  Can you report back on what speeds you were able to achieve?

Comment: @jcjones1515 removing the requirements.txt file massively increased the speed. Check the link I posted above for the already install libraries

Comment: without any requirements specified i am getting it 4-5 min to start. 
can we improve it?